# Access Windows Hard Drive In Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have a hard drive with data on it that I have been using as external storage in Windows 7...when I plug it into my Linux machine this is what I see:

```
/dev/sda 
Block device, size 596.2 GiB (640135028224 bytes) 
Status: Not mounted - Unsupported file system or disk not formated 
Status: Not mounted - Unsupported file system or disk not formated
```

What do I need to do w/o formatting and loss of data to be able to access this drive via Linux also?

It is an NTFS file system that is currently on the drive...and I am away from my computer so I can not verify which Linux distro I have running...

Comment: It seems as though you don't have the support files installed for whatever file system is on the drive. Without knowing this, nor what Linux you're running, I cannot say more.

Comment: @AFH it is NTFS file system...I am away from the PC at the moment so I can not confirm which Linux OS I am running.

Comment: In Ubuntu/Debian you need `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`. There will be an equivalent command in other distributions.

Comment: Without the critical details, anything that might be recommended is entirely speculation.  Your formatting could also use some work, as it seems to be being eaten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have `ntfs-3g` package installed as well as your kernel supports `fuse`. With `ntfs-3g`, you can mount like this:

```
    ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/tmp
```

Change the device to adequate. It's good you read the `ntfs-3g man`.