# how to mount internal NTFS drive in linux?

Tags: linux

I booted off an ubuntu 14.04 live USB pendrive on a laptop that normally boots windows 10 from it's internal solid state harddrive.

How do I access the harddrive from Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Windows Hard Drive In Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/869811/access-windows-hard-drive-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you have identified the device containing the volume you want to mount as `/dev/sdb1`, you should have to create a mount point like `/mnt/ntfs` then use the following command `mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ntfs`.

Comment: Possible problem: [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/693277).